# Geo coordinates from Shapefile in Android(.shp,.shx,.dbf)

Tags: android, arcgis

I'm working with Shapefiles and I want to convert the data to GeoJSON and extract the coordinates of the points (along with other information). However the coordinates do not appear to be latitudinal/longitudinal coordinates.

Shapefile Data :-
ENTITY: 1 | POLYGON (MBR 537321.690711082 6112547.202492061 537345.5606655972 6112593.402404027) [[POINT: 537325.7973699234, 6112549.51248766, POINT: 537329.647362587, 6112573.895774531, POINT: 537321.690711082, 6112575.9491039505, POINT: 537323.2307081465, 6112588.269080476, POINT: 537331.9573581843, 6112586.72908341, POINT: 537333.2406890718, 6112593.402404027, POINT: 537345.5606655972, 6112591.349074606, POINT: 537339.1440111566, 6112547.202492061, POINT: 537325.7973699234, 6112549.51248766]] | [Id (N) : 0.0]

Projection file data :-

PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55",GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",147.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Your data is in GDA94 / MGA zone 55 (EPSG:28355). You may want to convert it to WGS84 (EPSG:4326). Any GIS software like ArcGIS or QGIS will reproject it to WGS84

Comment: Thanks @antonio, But I am new to GIS I have no idea how to convert it programmatically. May you please suggest me some resources where I can find steps for conversion ?